# Animate widget flex in a column

Tags: flutter

I'm building a screen where I have a container in a `Column` with a set size and containing a `TextField`. When the `TextField` is focused, I want to animate the "Expansion" of this widget to take all the available space in the `Column` (just like If I wrapped it with a `Expanded` widget).

[image]

I know it exist size and scale transition widgets that I could use, but I would have to know the exact size of the available space left if the column which is not ideal.

Is there a way to animate the "flexibility" of a widget in a column like that?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. But check this out to get an idea. https://github.com/X-Wei/flutter_catalog/blob/master/lib/routes/animation_animated_widget_ex.dart
This is from an app called **Flutter Catalog** available on Play Store and App Store

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an `AnimationController`, an `IntTween` and an `AnimatedBuilder` as follows:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flex Animation Demo',
      home: FlexAnimationDemo(),
    );
  }
}


class FlexAnimationDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlexAnimationDemo({super.key});

  @override
  State<FlexAnimationDemo> createState() => _FlexAnimationDemoState();
}

class _FlexAnimationDemoState extends State<FlexAnimationDemo>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late final AnimationController _animationController;
  late final Animation<int> _flex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    // Define the duration of the animation in the controller
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      vsync: this,
    );

    _flex = IntTween(
      // Define the flex values between which should be animated.
      begin: 75000,
      end: 1,
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController,
        curve: const Interval(
          0.000,
          1.000,
           // Choose a curve to change animation speed acceleration
          curve: Curves.fastEaseInToSlowEaseOut,
        ),
      ),
    );
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flex Animation Demo'),
      ),
      body: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _animationController,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Spacer(
                  // User the value of the _flex Tween here to animated between the upper and lower flex values
                  flex: _flex.value,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 80,
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                  child: Text('Fixed height container')
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 25000,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    child: Text('Flexible container'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
      // A button to reset the animation
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _animationController.reset();
            Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 400), () {
              _animationController.forward();
            });
          });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've created a Column inside the AnimatedBuilder that has two flexible components (Spacer and Expanded) and one fixed component. The flex factor of the upper Spacer is animated using the `IntTween` `_flex`.

I've used large flex values (75.000 to 1 for the animated Spacer, 25.000 for the lower Expanded widget) in order to make the animation smoother. If you use low flex values, the animation stutters, since the animation needs to round the values to whole integers.

This gets you the following result (note that animation is actually smoother than in the gif):

[image: Demo of flex animation]

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -2):

Try animating maxLines property of TextField.

Following is a simple Flutter Application, where, if you tap on TextField, maxLines is set to a value relatively very high. TextField adjusts to the max height of screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _maxLines = 1;

  void expandTextField() {
    setState(() {
      _maxLines = 100;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter Sample'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20), child: Text('Hello')),
            Expanded(
                child: TextField(
              maxLines: _maxLines,
              onTap: () => expandTextField(),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Name',
              ),
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but that doesn't really animate the expand does it?