# How to animate a Flexible widget

Tags: flutter

I have a **Column** with many children of different height that appear and disappear when different state changes - therefore, the whole column's height changes. And so I have wrapped the Column in a **Flexible widget** like this: 
`Flexible(child: Column(children: [...]))` . Is there a way to **animate** the height changes of the Column?
I know I can remove **Flexible**, wrap the **Column** in an **AnimatedContainer** and animate it's height, but there are too many children in the Column and this looks very tedious. I was just wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810420/how-to-animate-expandable-flutter-widget-to-slide-it-out-of-the-screen